# C++ | MFC(SDI) | opengl : black screen

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc

i want to draw some openGl in a simple MFC :

process:

- i start a fresh project MFC/SDI
- i link opengl32.lib/glu32.lib to my project , i include gl.h and glu.h too.
- i implements the opengl's requierts methods (onCreate/precreate/PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR) (https://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S2085.aspx )
- i can build without error
- on my onDraw fonction, if i make nothing : nothing happend ! ( \o/)
- when i start to write some opengl code => black screen ( i test this code before, in a valid mfc-opengl project , and it's works )

my onDraw() :

```
 void CMFCopenGLtestView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC){
        ValidateRect(NULL);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
        wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, m_hRC);
        //://
        //  HERE i WANT TO DRAW SOME OPENGL
        //://
        SwapBuffers(m_hDC);
        wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, NULL);
        pDC->DrawText(_T("test"), 16, &rect, 1);
    }
```

onCreate()

```
int CMFCopenGLtestView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    // TODO: Add your specialized creation code here
    InitializeOpenGL();
    return 0;
}

BOOL CMFCopenGLtestView::InitializeOpenGL()
{
    m_pDC = new CClientDC(this);
    if (NULL == m_pDC) // failure to get DC
    {

        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!SetupPixelFormat(NULL))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (0 == (m_hRC =
        ::wglCreateContext(m_pDC->GetSafeHdc())))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (FALSE ==
        ::wglMakeCurrent(m_pDC->GetSafeHdc(), m_hRC))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // specify black as clear color
    ::glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    // specify the back of the buffer as clear depth
    ::glClearDepth(1.0f);
    // enable depth testing
    ::glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL CMFCopenGLtestView::SetupPixelFormat(
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR* pPFD)
{
    // default pixel format for a single-buffered,
    // OpenGL-supporting, hardware-accelerated, 
    // RGBA-mode format. Pass in a pointer to a different
    // pixel format if you want something else
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd =
    {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),// size of this pfd
        1,                      // version number
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |    // support window
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL,   // support OpenGL
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,          // RGBA type
        24,                     // 24-bit color depth
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,       // color bits ignored
        0,                      // no alpha buffer
        0,                      // shift bit ignored
        0,                      // no accumulation buffer
        0, 0, 0, 0,             // accum bits ignored
        16,                     // 16-bit z-buffer
        0,                      // no stencil buffer
        0,                      // no auxiliary buffer
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,         // main layer
        0,                      // reserved
        0, 0, 0                 // layer masks ignored
    };

    int pixelformat;
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR* pPFDtoUse;

    // let the user override the default pixel format
    pPFDtoUse = (0 == pPFD) ? &pfd : pPFD;

    if (0 == (pixelformat =
        ::ChoosePixelFormat(m_pDC->GetSafeHdc(), pPFDtoUse)))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (FALSE == ::SetPixelFormat(m_pDC->GetSafeHdc(),
        pixelformat, pPFDtoUse))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

If you have an idea about what i'm doing wrong i'm taking all of them !

Comment: Are you calling wglSwapBuffer somewhere?

Comment: You never check the return code from setting the pixel format.  Are you sure it's set correctly?

Comment: @DannyRuijters , i call SwapBuffers on onDraw() but no wglSwapBuffer because i read that's not recommended

Comment: @rriower , i forgot to keep my test so i'vs rechecked and : InitializeOpenGL(); return true and SetupPixelFormat too

Comment: Have you tried using something other than black for the `glClearColor()`? Does the clear color show up in that case, or is the window still black?

Comment: @RetoKoradi , if i change the value of glClearColor() , the background color change, does it mean something :) ? Is it possible that my 3D object draw himself below the backgound ? or something like that. thx

Comment: Yes, that means that your context creation and setup is most likely ok, and it's just your objects that are not rendering. The most common problem is probably that they are outside the field of view. But it can be a number of other problems. I list some possible reasons in an article on my personal web site: http://retokoradi.com/2014/04/21/opengl-why-is-your-code-producing-a-black-window/.